# copy_to_user: treating more data

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

In my kernel module I have the following read function:

```
static ssize_t sample_read(struct file *filp, char *buffer, size_t length, loff_t * offset) //read function here means to manage the communication with the button
{
    int ret = 1;
    int c;

    c = gpio_get_value( BTN );

    copy_to_user( buffer, &c, 1 ); //Buffer is the stack where to place the data read by function. copy_to_user copies the buffer on the user space. Here the reading is very simple. But if I would like to transfer more data?

    printk( KERN_INFO "%s: %s read %d from BTN\n", module_name, __func__, c );

    return( ret );
}
```

Here I copy to user space the value of c (that is the value of gpio) by buffer.

In case where for example I need to copy to user space more data using the copy_to_user function?

For example if I would like to copy to user space also a value int x = gpio_get_value( BTN_2 )?

Comment: What do you mean by `copy to user space more data` and `copy to user space also a value int x = gpio_get_value( BTN_2 )?` ?

Comment: You could export the device information/value from sysfs, alternative to using a struct.

Comment: Hi askb... I have not idea how to use sysfs. Can you do an example or a small explaination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in your code for `sample_read()` change

```
copy_to_user( buffer, &c, 1 );
```

to

```
copy_to_user( buffer, &c, sizeof(c));
```

Because the third argument should be `number of bytes` to copy, which should be size of data which you intend to copy to user space.

Next, `to copy more data`: use a struct. For example

```
typedef struct data {
    int x;
    int c;
} data_t;

data_t val;
val.x = gpio_get_value(BTN_2);
val.c = gpio_get_value(BTN);

copy_to_user( buffer, &val, sizeof(data_t));
```

Comment: Excuse me. I know that buffer is a char*, so when I am on User Space, how can I take the two values in User Space? Also in User Space I should make a data_t type through typedef to take these two values?

Comment: In user space, `typecast char*` to `data_t` and then read value